# Git authentication failed for https. on ubuntu

Tags: git, npm, gitlab

My package.json file has a dependency from our own gitlab server.

If i try to clone it using 'git clone https://...' git asks me for username and password. I provide it and package clones well.

But when i do 'npm install' i get

> 'fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://...'.

I already tried to add credentials using

> git config --global user.name 'username'
>
> git config --global user.password 'password'.

It didn't help.

What i need to do for successfull authentication?

I need to use https only, not ssh.

Package json related deendency

> "vueapp-services": "git+https://git.sanitas.com/sanitas-vue-modules/vueapp-services.git#develop"

Comment: Did  you turn on a two-factor authentication (2FA) in your GitHub account ?

Comment: @LeoR. no. should i?

Comment: No, but this bug can appear when 2FA is activated

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

`https://username:password@gitlab.com/username/repository.git`

But you must use environment variables for your credentials.

**Edit:** If you use 2FA, maybe you need to use access token like this:
`https://oauth2:ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/username/repository.git`

---

`<protocol>://[<user>[:<password>]@]<hostname>[:<port>][:][/]<path>[#<commit-ish> | #semver:<semver>]`

See also, https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

Comment: When i use this i get "URI malformed" and installing stops.

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`s related parts.

Comment: Edited question